# Disable checkbox array when radio button is not checked

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

Im trying to `disable` a checkbox array when the corresponding `radio` button is not checked. My code disables only the first element of the `checkbox` array and NOT the rest of the array. I might be doing something wrong but I cant seem to figure it out.

Any help would do.

**Javascript :**

```
<script>
  function radioDisable(){
    if(document.getElementById('rdGrp').checked){
      document.getElementById('txtUserID[]').disabled=false;
    }else{
      document.getElementById('txtUserID[]').disabled=true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

**html :**

```
<td>
  <input type="radio" name="rdAll" id="rdAll" value="all" onchange="radioDisable()"> All Users
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rdAll" id="rdGrp" value="group" onchange="radioDisable()"> Groups
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" id="txtUserID[]" value="SysAd"> System Admin |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" id="txtUserID[]" value="faculty"> Faculty |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" id="txtUserID[]" value="student"> Student |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" id="txtUserID[]" value="registrar"> Registrar |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" id="txtUserID[]" value="adviser"> Adviser |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" id="txtUserID[]" value="clerk"> Clerk | 
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" id="txtUserID[]" value="management"> Management
</td>
```

Comment: id is same for checkboxes. it should be different.

Comment: Id must be document wide unique. https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id

Comment: Id for checkbox must be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My code disables only the first element of the checkbox array and NOT the rest of the array.

That because `id` should be unique in same document, if there's multiple elements with same `id` just the first one will be selected, you could use name instead.

Use **[`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)** to get all the checkboxes and loop through them to disable/enable every one :

```
function radioDisable(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('txtUserID[]');
    var disabled = !document.getElementById('rdGrp').checked;

    for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
          checkboxes[i].disabled = disabled;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This one worked for me. Noticed most of the comments given are almost the same but this one did it for me. :)

Comment: Why duplicate the for loop? This can be much simpler.

Comment: Only catch with this, is that it's now doing the dom lookup for every iteration of the loop. It would be better to do it once and store the value in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

you've assigned all your inputs the same id "txtUserID[]", which is not allowed. If you would consider using jQuery you could simply assign a class to the inputs (you are allowed to use the same class mulitiple times, not id). It could look something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myClass">
```

In javascript/jquery

```
$(".myClass").disabled = true
```

Comment: Be careful there's no jQuery tag in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByName`

```
 function radioDisable(){
       var chkBoxes[] = document.getElementsByName('txtUserID[]');
       for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxes.length; i++) {
         if(document.getElementById('rdGrp').checked){
             chkBoxes[i].disabled=false;
           }
         else{
             chkBoxes[i].disabled=true;
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: This can be simplified to chkBoxes[i].disabled=!document.getElementById('rdGrp').checked

Comment: var chkBoxes[] is invalid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the duplicated id's, then you can use this...

```
function disableCheckboxes(){
    var chklist = document.getElementsByName('txtUserID[]');
    var chk = !document.getElementById('rdGrp').checked;
    for(var i=0;i<chklist.length;i++){
        chklist[i].disabled=chk;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ID from checkboxes and add class="txtUserID". then update your function like below

```
function radioDisable(){ 
  if(this.checked){   
    var allChkBox = document.getElementsByName('txtUserID[]');
    for(var i =0, len = allChkBox.length; i < len; i++) {
       allChkBox[i].disabled = this.checked;
    }      
  }
}
```

Comment: No need to use classes. Can just use name.

Answer (score 0):

Each element needs to have a **unique id** in HTML so you should not have the same id on all your checkbox elements. getElementById will only return one element because it expects the id to be unique, only the first checkbox will be disabled.

I would suggest that you give all these checkboxes a class:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" class="example" value="SysAd">
```

Then use [getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

```
var disableUser = !document.getElementById('rdGrp').checked;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");    
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].disabled = disableUser;
}
```

*Unique: Two elements cannot have the same id as one another.*

Comment: There is no need for class names. All checkboxes already have the same name, so he can just use getElementsByName instead

Comment: Either would work but I wasn't sure if the name was auto generated (square brackets in name).  Therefore it may have been safer to assign a new class.

Answer (score -1):

you do a common mistake. Your "inputs" do have the same "id". This is not right, an id should always be unique. If you want to access an element in Javascript you use:

```
var uniqueElemem = document.getElementById("txtUserID"); // returns only 1 element.
```

If you want to access a group of elements you use:

```
// returns an array of all elements which have the class "txtUserGroup".
var groupElem = document.getElementsByClassName("txtUserGroup");
```

So you have to change your HTML to something like this:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" class="txtUserGroup" value="SysAd"> System Admin |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" class="txtUserGroup" value="faculty"> Faculty |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" class="txtUserGroup" value="student"> Student |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" class="txtUserGroup" value="registrar"> Registrar |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" class="txtUserGroup" value="adviser"> Adviser |
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" class="txtUserGroup" value="clerk"> Clerk | 
  <input type="checkbox" name="txtUserID[]" class="txtUserGroup" value="management"> Management
```

Now you need to change your Javascript to this:

```
function disableButtons(){
  // get all elements with the groupClass
  var groupElem = document.getElementsByClassName("txtUserGroup");

  //is radio checked?
  if(!document.getElementById('rdGrp').checked){

    // Check if the array exists or has at least 1 element
    if (typeof groupElem !== 'undefined' && groupElem.length > 0) {

      //iterate through all elements which you want to be disabled
      for (var index = 0; index < groupElem.length; ++index) {

         // disable all elements with given class.
         groupElem[index].disabled=true;
      }
    }        
  }
}
```

PS.: You don't need to use Classes, there is a similar way with:

```
var groupElem = document.getElementsByName("txtUserID[]");
```

Hope this helps.

Regards, Megajin

Comment: You've duplicated the "txtUserGroup" ID. I assume this was supposed to be class="txtUserGroup"?